# How to use returned list from function, as function args in Python

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
    @property
    def randomcolours(self):
        return [int(x * 255) for x in colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(random.random(), 1, 1)]

    @tasks.loop(seconds=3, count=15)
    async def rainbow_embed(self, _, t, d):
        await self.bot.ini.edit(embed=discord.Embed(title=t, description=d, colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(*self.randomcolours())))
```

I am trying to pass the 3 returned values from `randomcolours` as the arguments in the `colour` kwarg but I am getting a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`, how can I do this?

Comment: Since `randomcolours` is a *property*, you don't use `()` to get the value.

Comment: ‘randomcolours’ is supposed to be a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randomcolours` is a `@property`, so an expression like `self.randomcolours` will call the function and evaluate to the list. Thus, when you *call* it like `self.randomcolours()`, you're actually calling the list returned from the property. It's not possible to call a list, so you get the error.

How to solve:

- don't call the list: `discord.Colour.from_rgb(*self.randomcolours)`
- or don't make `randomcolours` a property

Comment: I see, I guess I learned more about properties, thanks :)